# sudo: script launched from another script won't redirect standard output

Tags: permissions, sudo, aix, stdout

I'm using AIX 5.3 with sudo 1.6.9p23. Sudoers file grants user `fcomartin` permission to run any command as user `oas`:

```
fcomarti   ALL=(oas) ALL
```

User `oas` has a bash script called menu, which launches other scripts depending on the selected option.

The problem is that some of the secondary scripts redirect standard output to text file `temp` which is owned by `oas` user. When this happens the system tells me that user does not have the right permissions to write.

User `fcomarti` uses ksh, the used command is as follows:

```
sudo -u oas bash menu
```

(bash because user `oas` uses bash).

Menu starts and then menu launches monitorAv script. Inside monitorAv is the line `echo > temp`; it then errors saying user `fcomarti` does not have the right permissions to write.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've finally solved the problem, the sintaxis of sudo is as follows:

```
sudo -u oas bash -c "cd /Oas/bin; menu"
```

This is because some of the secondary scripts launched by menu, needs an absolute route to work.

Answer (score 0):

Edit that script, don't run `sudo something > here`, use it like this `sudo sh -c "something > here"`

`man` can be quiet useful, search for `redirection` in `man sudo`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i can't edit the scripts owned by user oas, the problem as i see it is that the secondary scripts launched by menu wont inherit the right permissions.

Comment: Did you try `sudo -u oas bash -c "menu"`?

Comment: Yes i have used that syntaxis, it keeps telling me: temp: The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.

Comment: You may try to use `groups` and `whoami` before that echo. To find out what user execs it. Which permissions are on the file temp.